# ¿Cómo hacer un bucle anidado para evaluar una ecuación diferencial en R?

Tags: r, bucles

Tengo una ecuación diferencial, la cual quiero evaluar variando los parámetros a y b:

```
Exp <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(t, state, parameters)), {
    dX <- (a * f + (1-b) * m) * (1- ((f+m)/k))
    dY <- (((1-a) * f) + b * m) * (1- ((f+m)/k))
    list(c(dX, dY))
  })
}
```

Actualmente, para evaluar la ecuación cree la siguiente función:

```
Genero <- function(Mercado,beta,EIM,EIH){


alphavec <- seq(.1,1,by = .1)
state <- c(f = EIM, m = EIH)
times <- seq(0, 10, by = 1)
parameters <- c(a = alphavec, b = beta, k = Mercado)

out <- vector(length(alphavec), mode = "list")
for(i in seq_along(alphavec)) {
  out[[i]] <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = TESIS, 
                  parms = c(a = alphavec[i], b = beta, k = Mercado))
}

out

}
```

El parámetro a esta contenido dentro dentro del vector alphavec, y con la función fijo los valores de (k, el valor del parámetro b, y los estados iniciales f y m). Así, la función me evalua la ecuación con un solo valor de beta, y variando los valores de a según el vector, arrojándome 11 tablas de valores.

La idea es, creando también un vector con todos los valores del parámetro b, ¿Cómo puedo crear un bucle, para que me evalue la ecuación combinando los valores de ambos vectores (alphavec = a, betavec = b)?

Y de lograr esto, ¿Como puedo crear una tabla en donde me arroje los resultados de cada combinación de parámetros? Igual a esta:

[image: Mapa del resultado de cada combinación de parámetros]

¡Agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: En la llamada a `ode()` la función es `func = TESIS` que no existe?. Debería ser 'Exp'?. Las derivadas X e Y en el modelo parecen depender solo de constantes, f, m y k? Por lo cuál no entiendo para que utilizas ecuaciones diferenciales, X e Y serían funciones lineales del tiempo ` t ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que TESIS sea un sistema de ecuaciones valido, para obtener las soluciones con todas las combinaciones de `a` y `b` una opción es iterar sobre `betas` para cada valor de `alphavec` con un loop for anidado:

```
Genero2 <- function(Mercado,EIM,EIH){
  alphavec <- betas <- seq(.1,1,by = .1)
  state <- c(f = EIM, m = EIH)
  times <- seq(0, 10, by = 1)
  parameters <- c(a = alphavec, b = betas, k = Mercado)
  
  out <- vector(length(alphavec), mode = "list")
  for(i in seq_along(alphavec)) {
    for (j in seq_along(betas)) {
      out[[i]][[j]] <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = TESIS, 
                           parms = c(a = alphavec[i], b = betas[j], k = Mercado))
    }
  }
  out
}
```